# xorg.conf for hybrid ATI/Intel

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, radeon

I'm trying to get my Intel HD 4400 and AMD Radeon 8670M working with the open source drivers. If I boot with an `xorg.conf` that includes:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Intel Graphics"
    Driver          "intel"
    BusID           "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "8670M"
    Driver          "radeon"
    BusID           "PCI:6:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Default Screen"
    Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
    Device          "Intel Graphics"
EndSection
```

Then I don't have a problem, but if I try and set the "Default Screen" to use the "8670M" device, I boot only into low graphics mode.

I am also getting various messages in `kern.log` such as

```
radeon 0000:06:00.0: No connectors reported connected with modes
```

`Xorg.0.log` gives similar sounding messages `Radeon no outputs connected`, `unable to definitely find connected outputs`, `Radeon(0): No modes`, `no screens found`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with this two video cards, and I still can't find the answers... With the Intel video card, I can only run Unity2D, but with the AMD card the graphical interface only start in low graphics mode.